# Can't add TextView to a new TableRow (The specified child already has a parent)

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

I was trying to add new `TableRows` to a `TableLayout` but I can't even add a `TextView` to a new `TableRow` object. But there is always the same error:

> **04-25 12:11:42.329: E/AndroidRuntime(26636):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.**

This is the main code:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

protected TableLayout mTableLayout;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_results,
            container, false);

    mTableLayout = (TableLayout) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.results_table);
    fullFillTable();

    return rootView;
}

private void fullFillTable() {
    TextView labelPosition = new TextView(getActivity());
    TableRow row = new TableRow(getActivity());
    labelPosition.setText("Pos");
    row.addView(labelPosition); //The error is here
    mTableLayout.addView(row);
   }
}
```

And here is the `fragment.xml`:

```
<TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/results_table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/results_titles_row"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#F7F7F7" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/results_col1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/results_col1_title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/results_col2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/results_col2_title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/results_col3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/results_col3_title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/results_col4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/results_col4_title" />
         </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are adding your `labelPosition` to two different views, which is wrong:

```
row.addView(labelPosition);
mTableLayout.addView(labelPosition);
```

Instead, you should add your `TextView` to the `TableRow` and add `TablewRow` to the `TableLayout`, like so:

```
row.addView(labelPosition);
mTableLayout.addView(row);
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed this. But the problem is in the first addView()

Comment: @marc_aragones, are you sure? Did you rebuild the project with the fixed code?

Comment: Yes, sure. The logcat says the error is at the line: row.addView(labelPosition);

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve it although not the way I wanted.

Create a `row_layout.xml` file:

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/col1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello world" />
</TableRow>
```

Then, inflate it:

```
private void fullFillTable() {
    TableRow row;
    row = (TableRow) View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.row_layout, null);
    ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.col1)).setText("Pos");
    mTableLayout.addView(row);
}
```

However, I would like to know why it wasn't working before.